# Force Orientation Change Not Always Working

Tags: ios, swift, uiinterfaceorientation

I am having an issue developing my iOS app.  I am basically creating a game that will require the user to use the system in portrait orientation at various times, and then transfer over to landscape.  They can't just auto-rotate, because it messes up the idiosyncrasies of the game.  I found a way to force whatever orientation I need at any given time by setting the proper supported orientations to help lock it specifically to that:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if self.currentGame == nil {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }
    else {
        return self.orientations
    }
}
```

Where normally the game is locked in landscape, but I can alter it by changing the `self.orientations` variable which is a `UIInterfaceOrientationMask`. So somewhere in the game if I need to change to landscape and lock it there I can go:

```
self.orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
```

Then actually force the rotation by having an action somewhere:

```
self.supportedInterfaceOrientations()
UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
```

This has actually been working great, although I was doing some alpha testing and messing around trying to find bugs.  So if I'm in portrait and then use this method to force rotation to landscape and then lock it there (or vice versa) it works just fine.  However, if for some reason I am holding the iPhone sideways so that it's not technically in portrait (even though it appears that way because it's forced to be), it refuses to rotate.

I know this method for forcing rotation is pretty much a hack anyways.  I'm wondering if somebody knows of a way to fix this problem, or if they even know of a better method for forcing rotation of device orientation.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!